# insta360 X2 OSC (open spherical camera) api call failed in preflight angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, camera-api

I am trying to send get call to the camera `http://192.168.42.1/osc/info` from angular ionic application . This request stuck in preflight. I suspect this might be the CORS issue and I had tried below code but this did not work.

```
getinfo()
  {
    const headers =new HttpHeaders({
      'X-XSRF-Protected': '1',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET'
    })

    this.http.get("http://192.168.42.1/osc/info",{headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log("Result:"  + data);
    return data;
  }, error => {
    console.log('Error'+ error);
  });
```

above get method is getting called in another ts file like

`this.results = this.servicename.getinfo();`

above result I am displaying in html page

I also followed the [INSTA360 OSC API LINK](https://github.com/Insta360Develop/Insta360_OSC) and passed the mentioned headers except content length as this is get call.

This same reqeust when I hit from the browser or from postman then it works and give the results. I also tried to change the host to [192.168.42.1:6666](https://192.168.42.6666) but not get expected result.
To avoid CORS error I change the Content type to text/plain but still got same issue
Is there anything I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CapacitorHttp](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http) plugin to use native http instead of angular. This is how I got around the CORs issue.

Comment: no luck. still getting same issue. request is getting initiated. and preflight request also get initiated but does not get response

Comment: Edit your question with the update code using capacitorHttp so we can take a look.

Comment: in page angular http was also there.I had removed the reference and its started working. Thank you very much from bottom of my heart